# Element not being selected dynamically from datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this list on my HTML page of country codes as part of a form:

```
<input list="countryCodesLst" name="countryCodes">
<datalist id="countryCodesLst">
...
<option value="93">
<option value="355">
<option value="213">
...
```

And I have this code in javascript after the list mentioned above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var codes = [{"BD": "880", "BE": "32"...}];
var what = $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {   updateResponse(response);}, "jsonp");


function updateResponse(data){
countryCode = data;
}
var CC = countryCode.country;
    console.log(CC);
function getValueByKey(key, data) {
var i, len = data.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (data[i] && data[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        return data[i][key];
    }
}

return -1;
}
var found = getValueByKey(CC,codes);
console.log(found);
var element = document.getElementById('countryCodesLst');
element.innerHTML = found;

</script>
```

However, even though I see that the code does found the value, it does not set the value in the dropdown list.
Can you please help me understand why?

Comment: You need to set the value of the `input` element, not the `datalist`.

Comment: I've changed the HTML and JS and it looks like this now:
 HTML: `<input list="countryCodesDataLst" name="countryCodes"   id="countryCodesLst">
  <datalist id="countryCodesDataLst">`  

JS: `var found = getValueByKey(CC,codes);
 console.log(found);
 var element = document.getElementById('countryCodesLst');
    element.value  = found;`

It still doesn't work though